# can i restrict user of website(like online test website) to change tabs?

Tags: reactjs, testing

I want to make an online test/quiz website in react js and node js, so I need something so that users cannot change tabs or windows to stop cheating

Comment: I think you can detect if the current tabs is not active. youtube player can stop when in the background for example. but that does not necessarily mean your user is cheating. they may be changing the music, got an urgent email they have been waiting for, or anything similar. so be advised to be careful if you implement such a feature

Answer (score 0):

using this you can check if the user has left the tab.

```
document.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
  // your custom code here
});
```

or

you can force full screen and show a warning if the user exits full screen. read about the full screen api [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

Comment: i have tried this code but it did not detect the changing tab

Answer (score 0):

You can try this HTML5 Visibility API.

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function (){
    document.hidden;
    alert('Don\'t change the tab.');
});
```